# Wordpress get attachments through function php

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to alter gallery shortcode in Wordpress through function.php, but no matter what, I got Zero result. This is my code in the simplest form:

```
remove_shortcode( 'gallery' );
add_shortcode( 'gallery', 'altered_gallery' );

function altered_gallery( $attr ) {
    global $post;   

    $attachments = get_children(array(
        'post_parent'=> $post->ID, // confirmed, right ID
        'post_status'=>'inherit', 
        'post_type'=> 'attachment', 
        'post_mime_type'=>'image', 
        'order'=> 'ASC', 
        'orderby'=> 'menu_order ID',
        'exclude'=> ''
    )); 

    $imageCount = count( $attachments ); // just to check

    echo $imageCount; // result 0, without ID, it will throw every attachment I have in every post
}
```

I saw several tutorials that suggest the same approach, including in SO. but I couldn't produce any result from that. What I did wrong? or is there a better way to get the attachment?

thx

Answer (score 0):

You must specific the `post_type`!

```
$attachments = get_children(array(
    'post_type'   => 'attachment',
    'post_parent' => $post->ID, // confirmed, right ID
));
```

Next time, please studying the Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children

Comment: I already did, I'm just simplifying what I think non-important code, guess I was wrong. Please check the edited code.

Comment: `'orderby'=> 'menu_order ID'` is **invalid** what says a `var_dump();`?

Comment: var_dump result int(0). I tried to use post_parent, post_type, post_per_page, post_status exactly like in codex and still nothing, got any idea?

Comment: Ehm, yep. I think: You write: you put it into `function.php`. But the filename must have the name `functions.php`

Comment: Otherway, what says `var_dump($post);`? I Think your Post ist not setted-up.

Comment: it's functions.php with s :) var_dump($post) result: object(WP_Post)#292 (24) { ["ID"]=> int(538) ["post_author"]=> string(..... etc etc